# How can i add set of information (in user defined data type) to an Array in java

Tags: java, arrays, input

I need to get(key board inputs) to store Name,ID,marks of several students and store them in an array..
how can i assign inputs to the array.. here is my code so far.. i am completely new to java. this is my first assignment..

does my data get stored in my Student[] studentDetails Array? or whats the code i need to add to do that.

```js
public class Main {
 
 
 
 public static void main(String[] args){
  
  Student s = new Student(null, null, null, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
  
  Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
  
  System.out.println("Enter no. of Student");
  int x = sc.nextInt();
  
  Student [] studentDetails = new Student[x];
  
  System.out.println("enter f name");
  s.setfName(sc.nextLine());
  
  System.out.println("enter l name");
  s.setlName(sc.nextLine());
  
  System.out.println("enter regno");
  s.setStuID(sc.nextLine());
  
  System.out.println("enter project 1 marks");
  s.setProjM1(sc.nextInt());
  
  System.out.println("enter ICT 1 Marks");
  s.setIctM1(sc.nextInt());
  
  System.out.println("enter Active P 1 Marks");
  s.setActP1(sc.nextInt());
  
  System.out.println("enter Codeing assignmnt Marks ");
  s.setCodeAsM(sc.nextInt());
  
  System.out.println("enter ICT2 Marks");
  s.setIctM2(sc.nextInt());
  
  System.out.println("enter Act. P 2 Marks");
  s.setActP2(sc.nextInt());
  
  System.out.println("enter ICT 3 Marks");
  s.setIctM3(sc.nextInt());
  
  System.out.println("enter Act. p 3 Marks");
  s.setActP3(sc.nextInt());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The single `Student s` is almost correct and you need to initialize `i` in your `for` loop. Something like,

```
for(int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
  studentDetails[i] = new Student(null, null, null, 0, 0, 0,
          0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
  System.out.println("enter f name");
  // s.setfName(sc.nextLine());
  studentDetails[i].setfName(sc.nextLine()); //
```

and then do something similar for all of the other inputs.

Comment: Thank you,, this will create one element for each student right? .so if i want to display whole array student by student is there other method than tosring override?

Comment: @Raveen The `toString()` method is the easy way; yes. Loop over the `Student`(s) and use your `getter` methods to retrieve each field and print it. Or Override `toString()` and call `Arrays.toString(studentDetails)`

Answer (score 0):

The array is of type Student. So it will store student objects. You can store store the student object directly.
like
studentDetails[0] = student;